# Problem using graphicx (includegraphics) in TeXstudio

Tags: graphics, miktex, texstudio, includegraphics

I'm (well, my girlfriend) is getting this bug in TeXstudio while trying to use \includegraphics. MikTeX is all up to date and graphicx was installed today... At first I was thinking the many packages loaded were clashing somehow, but after clearing the aux files and literally reducing the document down to

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{image}

\end{document}
```

we're still getting the error

```latex
Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
```

Yes, the image is a proper .png in the document's home directory, and I've done all the usual troubleshooting I could think of. I'm a pretty experienced LaTeX user but under MacTeX (on macOS, obviously) and I'm still figuring out MikTeX/TeXstudio. I figure it has something to do with how MixTeX installed graphicx but I'm pretty stumped with my limited knowledge of the distribution... Any help appreciated !

EDIT: For reference, here's the complete contents of the log file. Couldn't find many clues in there either...

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.11)  15 MAR 2020 17:30
entering extended mode
**"./Doc test inclusion d'image.tex"
("Doc test inclusion d'image.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen135
\Gin@req@width=\dimen136
)
(D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-23 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count175
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
("Doc test inclusion d'image.aux")
\openout1 = `"Doc test inclusion d'image.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(D:\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count176
\scratchdimen=\dimen137
\scratchbox=\box46
\nofMPsegments=\count177
\nofMParguments=\count178
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count179
\MPscratchDim=\dimen138
\MPnumerator=\count180
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count181
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
) (D:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
Runaway argument?
"D:/Latex/Exemples-bases/MontageDilution1.png" \edef \Gin@ext {\Gin@sepdefault 
\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

[1

{C:/Users/alice/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("Doc test inclusion d'image.aux") )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 2)

### semi simple group (level 2) entered at line 7 (\begingroup)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 7 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1125 strings out of 480910
 16198 string characters out of 2917146
 249766 words of memory out of 3000000
 17047 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532638 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 30i,4n,25p,207b,121s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<D:/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on "Doc test inclusion d'image.pdf" (1 page, 8398 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Show the complete log-file.

Comment: I assume you've tried compiling manually from the commandline?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please re-read the third sentence. Couldn't give many clues because the error message isn't amazingly detailed and I don't really have an idea as to what it could be referring to.

Comment: @TimHilt Haven't tried from command line because again, not an amazing Windows user and I don't want the solution to be command line-based.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep, added the log file. Hopefully someone sees something useful in there (I couldn't). Again, as mentioned in that third sentence, removing the aux and re-compiling was the first thing I did (and didn't solve the problem).

Comment: oh that is it.. You have an up to date latex (2020 release) but an old 2017 graphicx and graphics package that can not cope,. the log file should say `Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)`

Comment: you need to force miktex to update (at least) graphics.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Yeah I tried to update through the MikTeX package manager but it wasn't seeing an update for graphicx or graphics... Guess they have some sort of indexing issue. Will try to force the update and report back.